# Selenium Multithreaded Usage Performance Tuning

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium, testing, performance-testing

I am using multiple webdrivers with different threads. However, drivers are consuming a lot of memory and cpu usage. I am looking for efficient solution which can utilise many drivers usage with low memory/cpu footprint.

I have the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    Thread t = new Thread(this::workWithNewWebDriver, "Browser" + i);
    t.start();
}

public void workWithNewWebDriver(){
    ChromeOptions bestPerformanceOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(bestPerformanceOptions);
    driver.get("anysite.com");
    // Do stuff...
}
```

I am currently using that kind of user tests with selenium but framework is subject to change and I am looking for most performant lightweight solution.

Tests are only requiring user login and interactions, Any framework can click the button with a user is okay by me.

I have already tested the `headless` option for selenium but it only gives a slight improvement to performance metrics.

> Where can I find the preset of performant options for chrome driver?

> How can I improve the performance of selenium that tests 200 different parallel users use case ie.?

Comment: Do you need javascript rendering?

Comment: Selenium is known for huge RAM and CPU consumption. If you don't need JavaScript rendering use scrapy or BS4.

Comment: Btw you might aswell buy a big ass rendering server from AWS if you want 200 selenium browsers working in parallel. Thats nuts

Comment: it's not the right tool for load testing.  Having said that, using HTMLUnit will vastly increase the speed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can, real browser means real browser and real browsers are resource intensive. For example [Firefox 109](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/109.0/system-requirements/) requires 1 CPU core and 2 GB or RAM **per instance** and Chrome tends to consume even more.

Moreover [it is not recommended to use Selenium for performance testing](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/test_practices/discouraged/performance_testing/) in the Selenium official documentation, they suggest to use [JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) for that. Given you [properly configure JMeter to behave like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) from the system under test point of view there will be no difference whether you use Selenium or JMeter for testing.

Comment: that's not exactly requirements but recommended specs...  the point is very valid though, browsers are resource hungry and will try to use as much resources as possible for speeds sake.  That includes threads and memory.  Fairly recently they also isolated processes for different domains/contexts to fix some security holes.  That can add up very quickly... even for a single site you may see multiple chrome.exe instances.